# My car A/C lost all of its refrigerant

Tags: oil, ac, refrigerant

My car lost all of its refrigerant. I went to mechanic he checked my entire ac system for leakage but couldn't find any. He pressurized the cooling coil and also compressor but he couldn't find any leakage. After that he refilled refrigerant only. I used it for six months but now again my refrigerant gets low. My question is that I am worried  as he only filled refrigerant to the system is this ok as he didn't add any oil to the system. It is necessary to add oil or oil remains in compressor??? And what should I do as I lost refrigerant again  My car is just 30,000 km driven .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest you take it to a different mechanic, someone who specializes in A/C repair ... but that is just my humble opinion.

Comment: Thnx dear .... I myself thoroughly checked my whole ac System.... I saw very very minor  oil in Schrader valve cap of Low pressure ... Is it ok or it's the place where there is leakage .. pls guide me one more thing I tried to see the cooling coil from inside of my car and find no oil spot on it... Which in my opinion reflect that there is no leakage ☺️

Comment: The Schrader valve is one of many places it could be leaking. It is unlikely you would be able to see any sign of leaking from inside the vehicle. You do have a leak.  Take it to a mechanic who specializes in AC repair.

Comment: Thnx dear  for your prompt reply

Answer (score 2):

You clearly have a leak in your AC system as it is a closed system so the refrigerant had to have leaked out. Refrigerant leaks can be hard to find. They have special dyes and sniffers to help pinpoint the leak. When the refrigerant leaks out it is best to add some oil, but likely their is still enough oil in the AC system, so you are going to be OK. As @Paulster2 mentions you should take it to a mechanic who specializes in AC repair.

Comment: Thnx dear .... I myself thoroughly checked my whole ac System.... I saw very very minor oil in Schrader valve cap of Low pressure ... Is it ok or it's the place where there is leakage .. pls guide me one more thing I tried to see the cooling coil from inside of my car and find no oil spot on it... Which in my opinion reflect that there is no leakage

Comment: @MuhammadAshar Placing a balloon on the Schrader valve helped me to answer that question. It slowly filled up, letting me know the valve was leaking!

Comment: Great wow I am myself planning to do that but it's very minor leakage